# Install track for app not available on google play store

Tags: android, google-analytics, kotlin, google-play, google-play-services

I want to track installs from the website of my android app, my app is not live on play store.

Comment: you can store the number unique id in database in server and maintain the count

Comment: but how we know that from where the app is installed.

Comment: You need to use google statistics or google analytics to know the status whether it is installed or not which needs the app to be installed in google play store

Comment: yes i know this but i want to know that how to track if app not on play store

Comment: It is not possible without having the app on google playstore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible,
package manager apps send an intent to the apps they install with the referrer info.